# C++ Cannot integrate JPEG pipeline in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I've looked through tons of threads on OpenCV and Gstreamer and simply cannot resolve the issue to my error. I am trying to open a Gstreamer pipeline in OpenCV. I have built OpenCV with GStreamer and it says YES at the CMake step indicating that OpenCV built successfully. The command to retrieve the stream works fine from command line, however it just displays a frame and hangs in OpenCV.

My Syntax for Server:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device="/dev/video0" ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=640,height=480,framerate=15/1 ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=<IP Address> port=5000
```

My Syntax in OpenCV for Client (C++):

```
Mat frame;

//create video capture from video camera
VideoCapture cap("udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-
name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! autovideosink ! appsink");

cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
for(;;) 
{
    cap >> frame;

    char c = (char)waitKey(1);

    //![display]
    imshow(window_name, frame);

    frame.release();
}
```

The error:

> GStreamer Plugin: Embedded video playback halted; module
>   autovideosink0-actual-sink-xvimage reported: Output window was closed
>   OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: unable to start pipeline )
>   in icvStartPipeline, file
>   /home/dev/Downloads/OpenCV/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp,
>   line 383 terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'cv::Exception' what():  /home/dev/Downloads/OpenCV/opencv-
>   3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:383: error: (-2)  GStreamer: unable to start pipeline in function icvStartPipeline

Please provide any assistance I've been through at least 20 Stack posts and I am no closer to when I started with the exception of having Gstreamer enabled in OpenCV. I even tried different versions of OpenCV.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

VideoCapture cap("udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! appsink");

After a lot more digging through Gstreamer documentation today I solved the issue. The addition of videoconvert solved the issue. According to the Gstreamer documentation videoconvert automatically converts the data to the appropriate format for appsink. This allows it to be read correctly in OpenCV VideoCapture.